# open a gzip file when read by argparse

Tags: python, gzip, argparse, vcf-variant-call-format

I can open a gzip file easily as follows:

```
import gzip
import sys
file1 = gzip.open(sys.argv[1], 'rb')
```

I tried to use argparse:

```
import argparse
import gzip
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('vcf', help='gzipped VCF')
args = parser.parse.args()
```

When I tried to read my gzip file as follows:

```
with gzip.open(args.vcf, 'rb') as file1:
    for line in file1:
        print(line)
        if line.startswith("#CHROM"):
            print(line)
```

I got the following error:

```
TypeError: startswith first arg must be bytes or a tuple of bytes, not str
```

Since my line looked like with a `b` at the start of the line:

```
b'##fileformat=VCFv4.2\n'
```

I could fix the problem by using io.TextIOWrapper:

```
import io
with io.TextIOWrapper(gzip.open(args.vcf, 'r')) as vcf:
    for line in vcf:
        print(line)
```

Why did the first way did not work?

Thank you!

Comment: In the first case you are using `rb` which mean **reading + binary mode**. So changing `line.startswith("#CHROM")` to `line.startswith(b"#CHROM")` will fix the issue.

Comment: As has been said, the reason for the error-message is because a string is being compared to a byte. If you try `b'hello'.startswith("h")` you will get the same error-message. However, changing it to `b'hello'.startswith(b"h")` will return `True`.

Comment: What does this have to do with `argparse`?  The fact that you get `vcf` via `sys.argv` or `argparse` doesn't make a difference in how you open and read the file (provided they both get the same file name).